# Populate DataGridView with XML using C#

Tags: c#, xml, api, datagridview

I'm trying to populate a `DataGridView` with a dynamic `XML` file (generated by an API response - from ServiceDesk Plus, if it matters)
The API from the system I'm using replies a `XML` with the following format:

```
<API version="1.0">
  <response>
     <operation name="GET_REQUESTS">
        <result>
          <statuscode>200</statuscode>
          <status>Success</status>
          <message>WorkOrder Details Retrieved Successfully</message>
        </result>
        <Details type="GET_REQUESTS">
           <record URI="http://<myapiurl>/<workorderid>">
              <parameter>
                 <name>workorderid</name>
                 <value>01</value>
              </parameter>
              <parameter>
                 <name>requester</name>
                 <value>Some requester</value>
              </parameter>
              <parameter>
                 <name>createdby</name>
                 <value>Some technician</value>
              </parameter>
              <parameter>
                 <name>createdtime</name>
                 <value>1401967616186</value>
              </parameter>
              ...
              ...
            </record>

            <record URI="http://<myapiurl>/<workorderid>">
              <parameter>
                 <name>workorderid</name>
                 <value>02</value>
              </parameter>
              <parameter>
                 <name>requester</name>
                 <value>Another requester</value>
              </parameter>
              <parameter>
                 <name>createdby</name>
                 <value>Another technician</value>
              </parameter>
              <parameter>
                 <name>createdtime</name>
                 <value>1401967616180</value>
              </parameter>
              ...
              ...
            </record>
         </Details>
     </operation>
  </response>
</API>
```

Until now I was able to populate the `DataGridView` using the following code:

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(@"http://<myapiurl>/<post parameters>");

dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[6];
```

Yeah, it's quite simple.

But the results are displayed in the `DataGridView` like this:

```
name            value
workorderid     01
requester       Some requester
createdby       Some technician
createdtime     1401967616186
...             ...
...             ...
workorderid     02
requester       Another requester
createdby       Another technician
createdtime     1401967616180
...             ...
...             ...
```

And I need them to be displayed like this:

```
workorderid    requester            createdby            createdtime      ...    ...
01             Some requester       Some technician      1401967616186    ...    ...
02             Another requester    Another technician   1401967616180    ...    ...
```

I'm a beginner at c# programming (and also programming in general), so please forgive me If the answer is in my face. I'm trying to build a Winform so the users from my work will be able to see their pending helpdesk requests, but I can't figure out how to make each "name" key become a DataGridView Column, limited by the "record" key (I mean, when the program reach  it should create a new row, because it's another request)

**UPDATE**

Got some progress through using the following code:

```
foreach (XElement e in xml.Root.Descendants("parameter"))
  dataGridView1.Columns.Add("", e.Element("name").Value);
```

Now, how can I limit the columns? Or maybe select only the columns I need to display it's duplicating the columns for each "parameter" node (like workorderid, requester, createdby, ..., workorderid, requester, createdby, ...)
Also, I need to add the rows (of course), that would be the Element "value" (instead of "name")

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is how to chage *name/value* cloumn to custom cloumns and dynamic generic all the columns to the DataGridView.

If *dataSet.ReadXml* method will return one block of *workorderid* information from a data table, you can create the DataGridView by yourself, create the instance of DataGridView, write the column headers, write all rows by **grid.Rows.Add(xxx)**. If you want to get the code detail, add columns from vs designer, and than check MainForm.designer.cs, get the code out there and fill in your codes, that is very easy. And if you have other questions, comment on my post.

**For Updates**

First, create a *List columns* to cache all the different columns' name. In your case, if every work order's columns are the same, your *update* code could worked and run only in one *record* node. Otherwise, you need to  by *foreach* all "parameter" nodes. After that, you can choose the columns you want and add them. When you want add a row, just add to the cache and add to the grid when it is not duplicate.

Comment: I've edited my question with a better explanation, I don't think I was clear enough at first... I'm sorry, but I'm still lost..